# Django REST Framework - Migrate fails when splitting serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to split the models, serializers and views of my app to get small, readable files.

So, I moved from this:

```sh
app/
  recipes/
    migrations/
    models.py      
    serializers.py
    views.py
```

To this:

```sh
app/
  recipes/
    migrations/
    models/
      __init__.py
      tag.py      
    serializers/
      __init__.py
      tag.py
    views/
      __init__.py
      tag.py
```

Somehow, everything was working fine until I restarted Docker. Then, I realised `python manage.py migrate` couldn't handle this split, and fails with this error:

```sh
+ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 27, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/config/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    from config.api import api
  File "/app/config/api.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apps.recipes.views import TagViewSet
  File "/app/apps/recipes/views/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tag import TagViewSet
  File "/app/apps/recipes/views/tag.py", line 7, in <module>
    from apps.recipes.serializers import TagSerializer
ImportError: cannot import name 'TagSerializer' from 'apps.recipes.serializers' (/app/apps/recipes/serializers/__init__.py)
```

I've already read some articles and answers about code splitting, but I cannot see what I'm missing. My `serializers/__init__.py` is empty, and this is the code of my serializer (I took the simplest one to eliminate side-effects):

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from apps.recipes.models import Tag

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ['name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import classes into `__init__.py` to make them available.

Example:

*serializers/_ _ init _ _.py*

```
from .tag import TagSerializer

__all__ = (
    'TagSerializer',
)
```

Comment: I had indeed forgotten this, thanks! But even after that, in another Serializer I cannot use `from apps.recipes.serializers import TagSerializer`, I am forced to use `from apps.recipes.serializers.tag import TagSerializer`, any idea why? (that is in fact what was causing the migration to fail)